# Bifurcation points of system of non linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, bifurcation

I had a ODE of second order, then I built the following system of differential equations:

$$x' = y$$ 
$$y' = -\lambda sin(x) -2sin(x) -sin(x)cos(x)$$

With $\lambda = \frac{w^2}{\Omega^2}$ . I want to find the bifurcation points of the system. First of all I find the critical points, which are all of the form $(\pi k,0)$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let's focus on k = 0 for simplicity.

I tried to linearize it, and I got:

$$x' = y$$ 
$$y' = -\lambda x -2x $$

I hope it is right. Now, I find that the matrix of the system is

\begin{bmatrix}
    0      & 1 \\
   -\lambda    & -2 
\end{bmatrix}

The corresponding eigenvalues are: 
$x_{1,2} = -1 \pm \sqrt{1-\lambda}$

Is the procedure correct until now? What can I say about the stability?

Comment: is $\text{sen}(x)$ the same as $\sin(x)$

Comment: Yes, going to edit!